# Processing Toolbox, avoid using empty layer

Tags: qgis, error, merge, toolbox

I have a process (on the processing Toolbox) I need to reproject and merge two layers (result of previous operations). Sometimes, one of these layers will be empty, in that case it is not necessary to merge (indeed the process crashes if the layer is empty). Is there a way to specify that if the results are empty, don't merge it (but the process still continues)?